# Python 2.7 App executing as CGI instead of WSGI on App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine, cgi, wsgi

The following code generates a CGI method instead of WSGI as indicated in the log below.  Is this the normal execution for a WSGI app on the dev server?  If not what needs to change to get the application to execute as WSGI?

main.py

```
import webapp2
import wsgiref.handlers
import logging
from google.appengine.api import users


class HomeHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        self.response.out.write("Hi World")

app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
    (r'/', HomeHandler),
], debug=True)

app.run()
```

app.yaml

```
application: WSGITEST
version: 1
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: yes

libraries:
- name: webapp2
  version: latest

handlers:
- url: /.*
  script: main.app
```

Log

```
DEBUG    2012-05-09 21:31:14,921 dev_appserver.py:656] Matched "/" to CGI dispatcher with path main.app
DEBUG    2012-05-09 21:31:14,926 dev_appserver_import_hook.py:1246] Enabling webapp2: None
DEBUG    2012-05-09 21:31:14,928 dev_appserver.py:1624] Executing CGI with env:
{'REQUEST_ID_HASH': '77DE68DA', 'SERVER_SOFTWARE': 'Development/1.0', 'SCRIPT_NAME': '', 'REQUEST_METHOD': 'GET', 'PATH_INFO': '/', 'SERVER_PROTOCOL': 'HTTP/1.0', 'QUERY_STRING': '', 'CONTENT_LENGTH': '', 'USER_ID': '', 'APPENGINE_RUNTIME': 'python27', 'TZ': 'UTC', 'SERVER_NAME': 'localhost', 'REMOTE_ADDR': '127.0.0.1', 'SDK_VERSION': '1.6.5', 'PATH_TRANSLATED': '/home/bear/dev/appengine/code/ae-baseapp/401/main3.app', 'SERVER_PORT': '8080', '_AH_THREADSAFE': '1', 'CURRENT_VERSION_ID': '1.1', 'USER_ORGANIZATION': '', 'HTTP_USER_AGENT': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux i686; rv:12.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/12.0', 'HTTP_HOST': 'localhost:8080', 'HTTP_CONNECTION': 'keep-alive', 'USER_EMAIL': '', 'HTTP_ACCEPT': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8', 'APPLICATION_ID': 'dev~WSGITEST', 'GATEWAY_INTERFACE': 'CGI/1.1', 'HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE': 'en-us,en;q=0.5', 'HTTP_DNT': '1', 'CONTENT_TYPE': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded', '_AH_ENCODED_SCRIPT_NAME': '/', 'AUTH_DOMAIN': 'gmail.com'}
INFO     2012-05-09 21:31:14,933 dev_appserver.py:2891] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
```

Comment: how to you run your sdk? copy pasting this code does not produce the line where it states that its executing with CGI

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this log is a hardcoded string:

```
/usr/local/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/dev_appserver.py:
 1622      sys.modules['__builtin__'] = __builtin__
 1623  
 1624:     logging.debug('Executing CGI with env:\n%s', repr(env))
```

Comment: Gotta love assumption, my assumption was that Google would log WSGI vs CGI!

Answer (score 1):

First, you should remove this line of code because it's [incorrect](http://webapp-improved.appspot.com/api/webapp2.html#webapp2.WSGIApplication.run):

```
app.run()
```

As written in my comment and well pointed out by [aschmid00](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10524763/130929), could be an old debug statement.

Comment: are you sure about that? don't think app.run() will have any impact if you run it in py27 with threadsafe enabled... but i might be wrong.

Comment: @aschmid00 you get the DEBUG output by running `dev_appserver.py . --debug` // I don't think it runs the code twice as that would create an response of Hi World Hi World and all I get is a single Hi World

Comment: @systempuntoout - removing app.run did not change the execution mode from CGI to WSGI.  Use --debug on your applications and check if they show up as WSGI.